# Phrase matching in lists

Tags: python, list, tuples, phrase

Assuming I have a list representing a sentence ex:

```
sent = ['terras', 'ipsius', 'Azar', 'vocatas', 'Ta', 'Xellule', 'et', 'Ginen', 'Chagem', 'in', 'contrata', 'Deyr', 'Issafisaf']
```

and a list of place names

```
places = ['Ta Xellule', 'Ginen Chagem', 'Deyr Issafisaf']
```

how can I end up with:

```
[('O','terras'), ('O', 'ipsius'), ('O', 'Azar'), ('O', vocatas'), ('PLACE', 'Ta'), ('PLACE', 'Xellule'), ('O','et'), ('PLACE', 'Ginen'), ('PLACE', 'Chagem'), ('O','in'), ('O','contrata'), ('PLACE', 'Deyr'), ('PLACE', 'Issafisaf')]
```

A quick note:

If for example Ta has to be only next to Xellule. If found in another context in a sentence this should not be tagged as PLACE ex: Ta Buni mar Ta Xellule...only the second Ta should be tagged.

This is an example of my place list:

```
 'Ras il Huichile',
 'Ras il Hued',
 'Ta Richardu',
 'Roma',
 'Russilion',
 'La Rukiha',
 'Irrukiha ta il Bayada',
 'Casalis Milleri',
 'Ta Sabat',
 'Casalis Zebug',
 'Ta Zagra',
 'Sagra in  Ras il Hued',
 'Ta Isalme'
```

and this is an example sentence:

```
terras ipsius Azar vocatas Ta Xellule et Ginen Chagem in contrata Deyr Issafisaf cum iuribus suis omnibus
```

Here the in although it is present in Sagra in Ras il Hued should not be tagged as place

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried splitting each element in list places which works but not very efficient

Comment: I just gave an example of a sentence...even if you look at English sentences such as 'The dog and I went to The Hague' - The Hague is a place but the first The is not a place

Comment: So can you show us the code from your latest attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, I updated my answer based on your edit:

```
from functools import reduce

sent = "terras ipsius Azar vocatas Ta Ta Zagra Ta Zagra Xellule et Ginen Chagem in contrata Deyr Issafisaf cum iuribus suis omnibus"
places = [ 'Ras il Huichile', 'Ras il Hued', 'Ta Richardu', 'Roma', 'Russilion', 'La Rukiha', 'Irrukiha ta il Bayada',
'Casalis Milleri', 'Ta Sabat', 'Casalis Zebug', 'Ta Zagra', 'Sagra in  Ras il Hued', 'Ta Isalme', 'Ta Xellule', 'Ginen Chagem',
'Deyr Issafisaf']

places_map = {p:[('PLACE', l) for l in p.split()] for p in places}

def find_places(sent, places):
    if len(places) is 0:
        return [('O', l) for l in sent.split()]

    place = places[0]
    remaining_places = places[1:]

    sent_splits = sent.split(place)
    return reduce(lambda a,b:a+places_map[place]+b, [find_places(s, remaining_places) for s in sent_splits])

print(find_places(sent, places))
```

and the output is:

```
[('O', 'terras'), ('O', 'ipsius'), ('O', 'Azar'), ('O', 'vocatas'), ('O', 'Ta'), ('PLACE', 'Ta'), ('PLACE', 'Zagra'), ('PLACE', 'Ta'), ('PLACE', 'Zagra'), ('O', 'Xellule'), ('O', 'et'), ('PLACE', 'Ginen'), ('PLACE', 'Chagem'), ('O', 'in'), ('O', 'contrata'), ('PLACE', 'Deyr'), ('PLACE', 'Issafisaf'), ('O', 'cum'), ('O', 'iuribus'), ('O', 'suis'), ('O', 'omnibus')]
```

so I used a recursive method to find a place in the sentence change it in the format you want and do this recursively on the remaining parts of the sentence with the remaining places and then finally join them together.

Comment: but what if for example Ta has to be only next to Xellule. If found in another context in a sentence this should not be tagged as PLACE

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate and test:

```
for word in sent:
    isPlace = False
    for place in places:
        if word in place:
            isPlace = True
    if isPlace:
        result.append(('PLACE', word))
    else:
        result.append(('O', word))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like that:

```
res = []

for x in sent:
    for place in places:
        if x in place:
            # add 'PLACE' if it matches
            res.append(('PLACE', x))

    if ('PLACE', x) not in res: 
        # add '0' if we find nothing
        res.append(('0', x))

print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion based only on list comprehensions, for comprehension lovers:

```
sent = ['terras', 'ipsius', 'Azar', 'vocatas', 'Ta', 'Xellule', 'et', 'Ginen', 'Chagem', 'in', 'contrata', 'Deyr', 'Issafisaf']
places = ['Ta Xellule', 'Ginen Chagem', 'Deyr Issafisaf']

p      = [i for place in places for i in place.split()]
result = [('PLACE',word) if word in p else ('O',word) for word in sent]

print(result)
# [('O', 'terras'), ('O', 'ipsius'), ('O', 'Azar'), ('O', 'vocatas'), ('PLACE', 'Ta'),
#  ('PLACE', 'Xellule'), ('O', 'et'), ('PLACE', 'Ginen'), ('PLACE', 'Chagem'), 
#  ('O', 'in'), ('O', 'contrata'), ('PLACE', 'Deyr'), ('PLACE', 'Issafisaf')]
```

Comment: but what about if Ta can be found in another context in the sentence for example: Ta buni mar Ta Xellule. I only want the second Ta to be tagged as PLACE

Comment: Please give a concrete example of expected output in this new case. This is not clear enough IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it is to use `join` on `places` in order to create a string, and then check if the word is in that string:

```
sent = ['terras', 'ipsius', 'Azar', 'vocatas', 'Ta', 'Xellule', 'et', 'Ginen', 'Chagem', 'in', 'contrata', 'Deyr', 'Issafisaf']
places = ['Ta Xellule', 'Ginen Chagem', 'Deyr Issafisaf']

newList = [('Places',elem) if elem in " ".join(places) else ('O',elem) for elem in sent]
print(newList)
```

Output:

```
[('O', 'terras'), ('O', 'ipsius'), ('O', 'Azar'), ('O', 'vocatas'), ('Places', 'Ta'), ('Places', 'Xellule'), ('O', 'et'), ('Places', 'Ginen'), ('Places', 'Chagem'), ('Places', 'in'), ('O', 'contrata'), ('Places', 'Deyr'), ('Places', 'Issafisaf')]
```